# arranging the sections with \include

Tags: sectioning, include

As we know, it is possible to use `\include{chapter name}` to have a more convenient manuscript. The question is, is it possible to order the **sections** by meant of `\include` too?

Comment: you can `\include` anything, it is not tied to `\chapter` at all, but it must start a new page and you can not use `\include` in an included file.

Comment: The chapters appear in the order of the occurrences of \include.

Comment: You could always use \input instead.  You lose \includonly features, but it doesn't force a new page either.